# Input control floating placeholder stays on validation

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, email-validation

I am trying to achieve a floating placeholder functionality. Everything works fine with the code I have written except for the fact that when there is an email field and I try to add a wrong entry which is not of an email format and i shift focus from the input box, the floating text still appears. You can check the [codepen link](https://codepen.io/Aalind/pen/bMjXxa)

Belew is my code:-

```css
.-input-container {
    max-width: 540px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

input.-textbox {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 40px;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    padding: 16px 30px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #555555;
    font-family: OpenSans;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    line-height: 1.88;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    text-align: left;
}

input.-textbox:focus{
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: none
}

input.-textbox:focus ~ .floating-label,
input.-textbox:not(:focus):valid ~ .floating-label {
  top: 8px;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 45px;
  font-size: 10px;
  opacity: 1;
  line-height: 2.1;
  font-family: OpenSans;
}

input.-textbox ~ .floating-label {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  left: 45px;
  top: 18px;
  transition: 0.2s ease all;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="-input-container col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 ">
  <input type="email" class="-textbox form-control" required="">
  <span class="floating-label">E-postadress</span>
</div>
```

Comment: `input.-textbox:not(:invalid) ~ .floating-label` …?

Comment: Not possible pure CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
.-input-container {
    max-width: 540px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

input.-textbox {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 40px;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    padding: 16px 30px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #555555;
    font-family: OpenSans;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    line-height: 1.88;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    text-align: left;
    &:focus{
      outline: none;
      box-shadow: none
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="-input-container col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 ">
  <input type="email" class="-textbox form-control" placeholder="E-postadress" required="">
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for giving it a try but i want the floating placeholder functionality as well buddy.

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript in it. Try this

```js
$('input').on('focusin', function() {
  $(this).parent().find('span').addClass('test2');
});

$('input').on('focusout', function() {
  if (!this.value) {
    $(this).parent().find('span').removeClass('test2');
  }
});
```

```css
.-input-container {
  max-width: 540px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

input.-textbox {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 40px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  padding: 16px 30px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #555555;
  font-family: OpenSans;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  line-height: 1.88;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-align: left;
}

input.-textbox:focus {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none
}

input.-textbox:focus~.floating-label,
input.-textbox:not(:focus):valid~.floating-label, {
  top: 18px;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 45px;
  font-size: 10px;
  opacity: 1;
  line-height: 2.1;
  font-family: OpenSans;
}

input.-textbox~.floating-label {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  left: 45px;
  top: 18px;
  transition: 0.2s ease all;
}
.test2{
 margin-top:-20px;
 line-height:2.1;
 font-size:10px;
  font-family: OpenSans;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="-input-container col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 ">
  <input type="email" class="-textbox form-control" required="" id=spa>
  <span class="floating-label">E-postadress</span>
</div>
```

Comment: ya i thought about it. can we do it without javascript ?

Comment: As per i understand, there is no `CSS` code to check whether the field is empty or not. To check if the field is empty or not, you must use `javascript.`

Answer (score 0):

It is simple with some Javascript and minor changes in styles. Try this one.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.-textbox').click(function (){
        $(this).siblings('span').addClass('active');
    });
    $('.-textbox').blur(function(){
        if($('.-textbox').val()=== ''){
            $(this).siblings('span').removeClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.-input-container {
    max-width: 540px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    position: relative;
}

input.-textbox {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 40px;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    padding: 16px 30px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #555555;
    font-family: OpenSans;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    line-height: 1.88;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    text-align: left;
    &:focus{
        outline: none;
        box-shadow: none
    }
}
input.-textbox ~ .floating-label {
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    left: 45px;
    top: 18px;
    transition: 0.2s ease all;
}
input.-textbox ~ .floating-label.active{
    top: 8px;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 45px;
    font-size: 10px;
    opacity: 1;
    line-height: 2.1;
    font-family: OpenSans;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="-input-container col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 ">
    <input type="email" class="-textbox form-control" required="">
    <span class="floating-label">E-postadress</span>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks buddy. can you suggest me some way to do it without javascript ?

Comment: I spend some time on your codepen. What I understand is in pure css, the pseudo class ":invalid" affects both invalid email as well as empty value. This seems the real problem we need to fix. But if we use attribute "value" null, it effects the initial state while text field is empty. So I think script is the easy solution for this. But I will definitely let you know if I found some pure css solution. Thanks.